# Knockout JS 2.0 Binding Parse Error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this http://jsfiddle.net/Yp8Bz/? It works fine in Chrome/Firefox, but in IE 8 I get the following error:

```
Message: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Expected identifier, string or number;
Bindings value: click: blah, attr: {class: 'Hi'}
Line: 38
Char: 359
Code: 0
URI: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Put `class` in quotes. I ran into the same issue when using a reserved word.

```
attr: {'class': 'Hi'}
```

Comment: This also applies to `if`. In case anybody finds this page with the same problem I had.

Comment: @RichardDalton : what do you mean it applies to if? E.g.: if PropertyName == 1 && SubCollection.length ? should be if 'PropertyName' ? and for SubCollection.length ? Asking because I just have some problems with knockout 2.3.0 with IE8. Expected identifier, string or number line 2000 I put all my properties in quotes in the if as well. Same crap (I really hate IE) :(

Comment: @firepol I mean that when you are doing a `data-bind="if: something"`. The if should be quoted like so `data-bind="'if': something"`.

Comment: @RichardDalton thanks, you are the only person who points the `'if': something` issue out. Do you know when this is the case, it only seems to be an issue for me currently in this line `ko template: { name: 'conversation-template', data: negotiation, 'if': negotiation().conversation`

Comment: Thanks a lot! My issue was with 'for'.  So I changed `data-bind="for: something"` to `data-bind="'for': something"` and it fixed the IE8 binding issue.

Comment: Tried the same with for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937632/knockout-js-for-attribute-binding-in-ie8. Error disappears, but for attribute doesn't appears as well..

Answer (score 4):

Daniel A. White has already pointed out your specific problem, but if you were to be working with CSS classes on a regular basis, I would recommend using the `css` binding.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```
<div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0 }">
   Profit Information
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        currentProfit: ko.observable(150000) // Positive value, so initially we don't apply the "profitWarning" class
    };
    viewModel.currentProfit(-50); // Causes the "profitWarning" class to be applied
</script>
```