# Knockout js for attribute binding in IE8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

Can't bind for attribute in IE8

http://jsfiddle.net/k2Mq7/ - ko 2.1:

```
SCRIPT5022: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Expected identifier, string or number;
Bindings value: attr: { id: 'that-works', for: 'but-than-not' }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2Mq7/3/ - ko 2.1 quoted for ('for'):

jsfiddle fails but on my local machine no any errors but this label displayed without for attribute.

Is it Knockoutjs bug or that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: `for` is a reserved word in JavaScript and old IE does not like you to use it as a property name without putting it in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for responses, but actually I put it in quotes.. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/k2Mq7/3/ .. It doesn't throw error, but for attribute also doesn't exists on a label

Comment: put quotes around all properties...'attr', 'id', and 'for'

Comment: assuming you read the SO @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140236/using-conditional-knockout-templates-with-ie8/10141205#comment32966221_10141205

Comment: @beauXjames that doesn't helps (in my actual example i have only for attribute data-bind="attr: { 'for': IdPrefix + '-sort-direction' }")

Comment: you didn't wrap attr in quotes in your 'actual example'

Comment: Nope that doesn't works too.

Comment: your second fiddle seems to work fine for me in IE8. look for the `htmlFor` attribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533872(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use quotation marks for attributes names like this:

```
<label data-bind="attr: { 'for': vmProperty }"></label>
```